Constructor-based injection vs Property-based injection which to use?
Should I use Constructor-based injection or Property-based injection or follow different approach.
interface Human {
    eat(): void;
    sleep(): void;
}

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService implements Human{
    constructor(){

    }

    async eat(){
        console.log("Employee Eats");
    }

    async sleep(){
        await this.beforeSleep();
        console.log("Employee Sleep")
    }

    async beforeSleep(){
        console.log("Checking mails....")
    }
}


@Controller()
export class EmployeeController{
    constructor(private readonly _employeeService:EmployeeService){}

    async eat(){
        this._employeeService.eat();
    }
}


In my EmployeeController I dont want to see beforeSleep function. I want to use property based injection like this
constructor(  @Inject(EmployeeService.name) private readonly _employeeService:Human ){}
But as per docs it says
"If your class doesn't extend another class, you should always prefer using constructor-based injection. The constructor explicitly outlines what dependencies are required and provides better visibility than class attributes annotated with @Inject."
I am very much confused because my every service has Interface that it implements. And i also don't want to show more information than it is needed.
Should i make another service for beforeSleep function and inject on EmployeeService?
Which should i do?

Both of these are examples of constructor based injection, one is using the inherent typescript emitted metadata when decorators are present, and the other is explicitly setting the metadata to be read by Nest instead (i.e. using @Inject()). For your case and scenario, it seems like the explicit injection of the token to an interface (using @Inject()) is the better approach here, as it'll allow you to "hide" some of the properties of the value being injected and leave the class that the value is being injected into to just worry about the interface.

Property based injection, on the other hand, is for when you have things like a BaseService that needs to have ConfigService/LoggerService/some other common service or provider injected into it, but you don't want to always have to inject it in the child classes.
export abstract class BaseHuman implements Human {
  @Inject(LoggerService)
  protected: logger: LoggerService;
}

With this, and your EmployeeService now extending BaseHuman instead of implements Human, you'd be able to add this.logger.log('whatever') to the calls, even though the LoggerService isn't mentioned in the constructor, because Nest can still read the metadata of the parent class and inject based on the properties, hence property-based injection.
